# How to authorize multi api keys using @nestjs/swagger and @UseGuards?

Tags: typescript, swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

I'm using @UseGuards to validate two api keys in header.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): boolean {
  // check two api keys('some' and 'thing') in header at once
}
```

Also, I'm using @ApiHeader in Controller to show in swagger.

```
  @ApiOperation({ summary: 'blah blah' })
  @ApiHeader({ name: 'some'}, {name: 'thing'})
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Get('/hello')
  async adminableCollections() {
    // do something
  }
```

**I want to use @ApiSecurity or some what instead of @ApiHeader to authorize at one time using authorize button(in the picture), not entering values to every method.**
[image: swagger Authorize button that can authorize all methods i want]

I tried to add custom security using document builder, but it seems to not workig at all.

```
  const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
    .setTitle('My API')
    .setDescription('Document for my api.')
    .setVersion('0.0.1')
    .addApiKey('some', { type: 'apiKey', in: 'header', name: 'some' })
    .addApikey('thing', { type: 'apiKey', in: 'header', name: 'thing })
    .build();
```

is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I solved with [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/pull/1230)

AuthGuard was no needed in this problem.
I just add apikeys in swagger config and add decorators on method I want.

Answer (score 7):

AuthGuard isn't needed for this.

And in case someone needs an example

main.ts

```
import {DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule} from '@nestjs/swagger'

const swaggerConfig = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('API REST')
  .addApiKey({type: 'apiKey', name: 'Api-Key', in: 'header'}, 'Api-Key')
  .build()
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(api, swaggerConfig)
SwaggerModule.setup('api', api, document)
```

controller.ts

```
import {ApiSecurity} from '@nestjs/swagger'

@ApiSecurity('Api-Key')
@Controller({path: 'entities'})
export class EntityController {
  ...
}
```